# use ngIf as dynamically show template and hide template in Angular 5

Tags: angular

i am using div tag in html

```
<div *ngIf="mydummy">hi</div>
```

and in ts file  and by default  this.mydummy is true(now div tag is visible)

but i do set-timeout function to make value  equal to false 
the ngIf not working it acts like one time use. so is  there  any option to achieve this simple task

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

      this.mydummy =  false

    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use arrow Function inside setTimeout.

```
ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.mydummy = false;
    }, 4000);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3knqs

Comment: thx working fine